# Do "пролить кровь" and "лишить жизни" mean the same in Russian?

Tags: значения

Do both of them imply killing? Is it possible to "пролить кровь" of somebody, but not take his life?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Лишить жизни*, by its meaning, always means *to kill*.

Most of the times, *пролить кровь* means the same thing, however it may also mean *to inflict serious wounds*.  There is also version *пролить свою кровь*, which may mean *to suffer* (without necessarily dying). For example, *Я за это кровь проливал*.

Here's an article on [wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C), which has a mention of this meaning, yet it doesn't provide any examples.

**EDIT:** A couple of people pointed out in comments a phrase like *Я за таких как ты кровь проливал* - this is indeed a very good example that just didn't come to my mind when I was writing the answer.  I'm removing the reference to 'rare usage'.

Comment: Example: "Да я за таких как ты кровь проливал" - obviously the speaker is not dead. Search with Google gives 2M matches.

Comment: @Artemix good point, indeed.

Comment: Большой словарь русских поговорок: Проливать/ пролить [свою] кровь Разг. 1. за кого, за что. Погибать, защищая кого-л., что-л. 2. Сражаться, воевать. БМС 1998, 317; СОСВ, 153; Верш. 4, 365.

Comment: This is a VERY widespread usage. I do not know why you label it "rare".

Answer (score 3):

These expressions actually translate into English quite well.

- лишить жизни -- to take (someone's) life
- пролить кровь -- to shed (one's) blood

Just as "to take a life", "лишить жизни" necessarily means "to kill". On the other hand, "to shed blood" and "пролить/проливать кровь" means "to fight for something", but does not necessarily imply dying. It can also mean "to cause harm to somebody", as in "to shed blood of innocent people".  In this case it usually does imply killing.